# How to position box to the righter side of the website?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an issue here, I'm trying to place an box to the right side of the website and I don't know why it is not working, I tried `justify-content: flex-end;` to flush the box at the "end" of the page and then add a `padding-right` of `200px`, but that sadly doesn't work. Any help with explanation would be appreciated.

```css
   

 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: #1f2937;
    position: static;
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column; 
    justify-content: center; 
  }

 
  
  .footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: #1f2937;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .logo {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    color: white;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 200px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
  }
  
  .navbar {
    color:white;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 85%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 200px;
  }
  
  .navbar ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px; 
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .text1 {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 200px;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 720px;
  }
  .text2{
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 200px;
    width: 520px;
  }


  .placeholder{
  width: 500px;
  height:350px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  display:flex;
  }


  .text3{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center; /*vertical center*/
    justify-content:center; /*horizontal center*/ 
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Website</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <h2>Header Logo</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">header link one</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">header link two</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">header link three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="text1">
      <h2>This website is awesome</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="text2">This website has some subtext that goes here under the main title.It's a smaller font and the color is lower contrast</div>
    <div class="text3">this is a placeholder for an image</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Copyright © The Odin Project 2023
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried to sort it with justify content flex end and am at my wits end, to be fair, an explanation to my issue would be very helpful to further my understanding, I've only included the necessary CSS Code and the whole HTML file. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Set the width of `text3` to 100%. The `text3` div is left aligned. It's only the *content* in it, that's right aligned.

Answer (score 0):

ok so first of all, you are using flex properties even though you havent set display:flex;

second-to make a div go right (for eg. box):(also indent according to will)

````
.container{
display:flex;
align-items:center; /*vertical center*/
justify-content:right; /*horizontal center*/
}```
#text{
display:block;
}
````

Comment: thanks for your quick and helpful response! Sadly it still didnt quite work I would share my whole css code with you, If you didnt mind. Is it possible that you could help me out? Im a new aspiring self taught programmer and really stuck on this problem.

Comment: I can provide help if you share the entire code also I'm also a self taught programmer.

Comment: Hello,
thanks for  wanting to help me, Ive changed the code to include all of CSS. this is how it looks right now https://imgur.com/a/eB5MCHH.
Ideally I want the grey container to be on the right side, vertical center

Comment: As well as the text in the grey container to be centered vertically as horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

`justify-content: flex-end` on your box won't achieve the result that you want for 2 reasons:

1. Your box isn't a flex element, `justify-content` and `align-items` are set on the element which has `display: flex;` and affect all of it's children.
2. Your giving your container element `flex-direction: column;`. This also comes with the effect, that `justify-content` now acts as vertical alignment. To move all elements to the right, you would have to use `align-items: flex-end;`

Since you only want to move your box element to the right, you have to give it `align-self: flex-end;`

Here's the reworked code:

```css
.text3 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  padding-right: 200px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: #1f2937;
  position: static;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Website</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <h2>Header Logo</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">header link one</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">header link two</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">header link three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="text1">
      <h2>This website is awesome</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="text2">This website has some subtext that goes here under the main title.It's a smaller font and the color is lower contrast</div>
    <div class="text3">this is a placeholder for an image</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Copyright © The Odin Project 2023
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I would suggest giving [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) a read. It will help you get a better understanding of how flexbox works.

Comment: Thank you, Ive understood that .text3 is a flex item within the flexcontainer .container. how do i move the whole flex item within the .container to the right side? with the text? sorry for the long response

Comment: If you want to move the text to the right side as well, you just need to give your .text3 item `text-align: right;`. Note that you still have a padding on the right side of your .text3, which will cause the text to not fully align to right unless you remove said padding. Does this answer your question?